# How to see if the directory exists?

Tags: shell, shell-script, files, directory, test

How can I check if `/bin/x86_64/bin/ls` is a directory in a bash shell script

Here is what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    if [[ "$1" = /* ]]
    then
    cd ./bin/x86_64/bin/ls
        if [ -d "$1" ]; then
            echo "ok"
            i="$1"
            echo $i
        else
            echo "error2"
            exit
        fi
    else
        echo "error"
        exit
    fi
fi
```

Comment: did you mean `if [[ "$1" = "/*" ]]`?

Comment: the `cd ./bin/x86_65/bin/ls` seems unusual.  Try a format more like `cd "/bin/x86_64/bin"` using quotes and omitting the ls at the end as that is probably a command not a directory.

Comment: Also, do you get an error ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following to check for the existence of a directory:

```
if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
```

If you want to check for any file you would use

```
if [[ -e "$1" || -L "$1" ]]; then
```

If you want to check if a file is a regular file (or symlink to regular file), but NOT a directory (or a device, socket, named pipe...) file then you can use:

```
if [[ -f "$1" ]]; then
```

If the file might exist but you want to be sure it is not zero size:

```
if [[ -s "$1" ]] then;
```

All those tests are based on the result of the `stat()` system call (except for `-L` that relies on `lstat()`). If you don't have the permission to do such a call on the file (for example because you don't have search access to the directory the file is in or to directories involved in the resolution of the file for symlinks), then those tests will silently return false as if the files didn't exist.

`[[ ... ]]` is a `ksh` operator, also supported by `bash` and `zsh`. The standard equivalent (to use in `sh`) is with the `[` command (for the second example above, use `[ -e "$1" ] || [ -L "$1" ]`).

Comment: doesn;t work :(

Comment: In what way and AGAIN what error(s) do you get?  It's good that you provide the details of what you have attempted, however you are unlikely to get much help unless you respond to the requests for more details about what error or response you get.

Comment: If you use single brackets these commands will have more compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, if the directory you `cd` to actually exists.

I changed the `cd` line to a directory on my system (diff):

```
-    cd ./bin/x86_64/bin/ls
+    cd /bin/
```

Then ran:

```
ry@~/Desktop:$ sh test /bin /
ok
/bin
```

Note that you must feed your script two arguments because of this: `if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then`

Also, note that `./bin/` is actually the same as `bin/`.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a directory exists in a shell script you can use the following:

```
dir=$1

if [ -d "$dir" ]; then

 #means that $dir exists.

fi
```

to check the opposite , add ! before the -d -> `[ ! -d ....]`